# Como fazer uma pesquisa em um campo combo a medida que for digitando o texto?

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

eu tenho um campo combo com mais de 2.000 registros.
Fica difícil selecionar o que preciso.

Eu estou precisando de algo (Bootstrap?) que a medida que for digitando uma parte da palavra o combo vai se posicionando no texto digitando.

Procurei alguns exemplos mas muito complexos. Talvez em bootstrap tenha algo mais simples. Alguém conhece?

Uso Laravel 5.2

Obg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apenas com Bootstrap você nao consegue realizar essa tarefa. [Nesse link](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/30-plugins-de-jquery-e-ajax-para-autocomplete) você encontra 30 exemplos em jQuery que fazem esse trabalho. Procure o que mais se adeque às suas necessidades.
Alguns dos exemplos também podem ser encontrados abaixo:

- [Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)
- [Plugin jQuery: AutoComplete](http://www.codenothing.com/archives/jquery/auto-complete/)
- [Sugestões aleatórias](https://github.com/dbunic/REDIPS_autocomplete)

E por fim, um exemplo JS+HTML que peguei pronto e tentei simplificar. Aqui você pode inserir uma linguagem como Python, Cobol, Fortran e ele será autocompletado:

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" class="form-control">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

O link postado pelo @guilherme-reis é de 2012 e talvez não resolva teu problema.

O [Typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) é um plugin para jQuery feito pelos caras que fizeram o Bootstrap.

Neste artigo do [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-smart-search-with-laravel-and-typeahead-js) eles explicam como usar Laravel e Typeahead.

Resumo:

**HTML**:

```html
<input type="search" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
```

**Javascript**:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Set the Options for "Bloodhound" suggestion engine
    var engine = new Bloodhound({
        remote: {
            url: '/find?q=%QUERY%',
            wildcard: '%QUERY%'
        },
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('q'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });

    $(".search-input").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        source: engine.ttAdapter(),

        // This will be appended to "tt-dataset-" to form the class name of the suggestion menu.
        name: 'usersList',

        // the key from the array we want to display (name,id,email,etc...)
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'
            ],
            header: [
                '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
            ],
            suggestion: function (data) {
                return '<a href="' + data.profile.username + '" class="list-group-item">' + data.name + '- @' + data.profile.username + '</a>'
      }
        }
    });
});
```

**Route**:

```php
Route::get('find', 'SearchController@find');
```

**SearchController**:

```
public function find(Request $request)
{
    return User::search($request->get('q'))->with('profile')->get();
}
```

O autor utiliza uma trait para que os models tenham uma melhor funcionalidade de *search*: [nicolaslopezj/searchable](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable)

O artigo contém detalhes da implementação do model e aprofundamento do assunto.